# How to get distinct record from database query in django?

Tags: django, database

I have following record in messages table:

[image: table]

and I want to get all the **receiver** where the **sender** is 15 and all the **sender** where the **receiver** is 15.

I used this query:

```
return Messages.objects.filter(Q(sender=15) | Q(receiver=15)).distinct()
```

but it returns duplicates results also as follows:

[image: output]

How can I get only the distinct/unique records. For example  {sender: 15, receiver: 11} should never repeats

Answer (score 1):

You can work with:

```
Messages.objects.filter(sender=15).values_list('receiver', flat=True).union(
    Messages.objects.filter(receiver=15).values_list('sender', flat=True)
)
```

Comment: this returns null

Comment: @Ruma: it can not return `null`, it at least returns a `QuerySet` that might be empty, but not `NULL`. Can you share what the query looks like with `print(qs.query)` with `qs` the `QuerySet` that is constructed).

Comment: @Ruma: locally, I got ``(SELECT `app_name_message`.`receiver_id` FROM `app_name_message` WHERE `app_name_message`.`sender_id` = 15) UNION (SELECT `app_name_message`.`sender_id` FROM `app_name_message` WHERE `app_name_message`.`receiver_id` = 15)``.

Comment: I tried this but this is returning empty array/object

Comment: @Ruma: If I add `Messages` objects locally, I get a `<QuerySet [2]>`, so a `QuerySet` that here contains *one* element: a `2`.